# DSE Graph Loader error with sample CSV file

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I'm trying DSE Graph Loader. DSE graph loader version is 5.0.3. I'm using Virtual Box image downloaded from DataStax website.

When I'm following instruction from https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/dgl/dglCSV.html. It always failed with two types of errors as below.

> ERROR DataLoaderImpl:594 - Graph driver attempts exceeded for this
>   operation, logging failure, but no records are present (may have been
>   a schema operation)
>   com.datastax.dsegraphloader.exception.TemporaryException:
>   om.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unrecognized
>   option string: graph.tx_groups.default.verify_unique
>
> 2016-11-23 13:38:41 ERROR DataLoaderImpl:594 - Could not load record
>   [{gender =F, name=Julia Child}] on load [author] for source record
>   [CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={name=0, gender =1}, recordNumber=1,
>   values=[Julia Child, F]]] java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer. But after I tried same thing on OSX, it worked without any issues. So the problem is related to VM environment.